# Flutter App login and should check username and password which are entered by the user with the values returned from api

Tags: api, spring-boot, flutter, dart

I am creating an application where it should validate the username and password entered by the user with the username and password returned by the spring-boot API which fetches the details from the MySql Database. How could I achieve it, thanks in advance

Comment: Are you trying to fetch username and password to client side for validating?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this kind of case the most appropriate would be to make a login screen where the user enters the username and password then you send the info to your API which will take care of doing this verification then send a response to the application already giving the status of the verification.

So basically you have to do:

1. Make an end point which receives the user name and password parameters which you obviously have to test with simple tools like POSTMAN or other to make sure that it works correctly
2. Build a flutter interface that recovers the user name and password
3. Consume the API
4. interpret the result.

::: Sorry if the English is a little weird I used a translator.